# find immediate tr elements of table element using jquery find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, find

I am trying to find all tr elements inside a table element. The table element it self has other table elements nested inside its rows. So when I do the following:

```
$(tbl).find('tr').hover(...);
```

...it picks up tr elements inside the nested table elements also. I just want the immediate tr elements of the table element I am trying to query.

`$(tbl).find('>tr').hover(...);` didn't work for me!

ps: `tbl` is a table element, not a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read full answer, please.

```
$(tbl).children()
```

will give you `tbody` and also `thead` if it exists.
So if you want immediate tr, you will need to try this.

$(tbl).children('tbody').children('tr')

Don't forget to consider`tbody` while fetching children of a `table`, as in Firefox a direct call to children like `$(tbl).children()` returns `tbody` and not `tr`, even if its not in your markup. Complex but useful.

Happy Coding.

Comment: I don't know about tbody existence, but I'd so something like:

`if ($(tbl).children('tbody').size() > 0) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(tbl).children('tr').hover(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(tbl).children('tr').hover(...);
```

Form the [JQuery docu](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that - even if your markup doesn't include them - from a DOM point of view, tr elements are nested inside a tbody element, so you will need to include this in the selector.

Try something like...

```
$(tbl).find('tbody>tr').hover(...);
```

Although this will probably find the nested table's tbody too, so you'll probably need something like...

```
$(tbl).children().find('tr').hover(...);
```